# Is a static method containing loops thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, loops

I have a huge loop that I wanted to split up into 4 threads. I've done so using a little bit noobish method(or maybe not?) and split up the counter of the for loops into 4 intervals, created a new Printwriter, and CrucibleOptimizer for each thread so that there are no conflicts, like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable run1 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            PrintWriter writer1;
            try {
                writer1 = new PrintWriter("test_result1.txt");
                CrucibleOptimizer optimizer1 = new CrucibleOptimizer();
                int[] loop1boundries = new int[]{1, 7};
                opt(optimizer1, writer1, loop1boundries[0], loop1boundries[1]);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("File not found");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Runnable run2 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            PrintWriter writer2;
            try {
                writer2 = new PrintWriter("test_result2.txt");
                CrucibleOptimizer optimizer2 = new CrucibleOptimizer();
                int[] loop2boundries = new int[]{8, 14};
                opt(optimizer2, writer2, loop2boundries[0], loop2boundries[1]);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("File not found");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Runnable run3 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            PrintWriter writer3;
            try {
                writer3 = new PrintWriter("test_result3.txt");
                CrucibleOptimizer optimizer3 = new CrucibleOptimizer();
                int[] loop3boundries = new int[]{15, 22};
                opt(optimizer3, writer3, loop3boundries[0], loop3boundries[1]);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("File not found");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Runnable run4 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            PrintWriter writer4;
            try {
                writer4 = new PrintWriter("test_result4.txt");
                CrucibleOptimizer optimizer4 = new CrucibleOptimizer();
                int[] loop4boundries = new int[]{23, 30};
                opt(optimizer4, writer4, loop4boundries[0], loop4boundries[1]);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("File not found");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[]{new Thread(run1), new Thread(run2), new Thread(run3), new Thread(run4)};
    for (Thread thr : threads){
        thr.start();
    }
}
```

And this is the method that I'm asking about. I don't know if its thread safe. I've been reading around and google says that as far as I don't have any local variables, I'm fine, but what concerns me is the multiple counters in those loops:

```
    public static void opt(CrucibleOptimizer opt, PrintWriter writer, int minIncluded, int maxIncluded){
    //more than this is never used
    final int oreMaterialsMaximum = 100;//100
    final int ingotMaterialMaximum = 30;//30

    //test for every possible material combination
    for (int a = minIncluded; a <= maxIncluded; a++){//for amount of ingots
        System.out.println("Testing for ingot number: " + a);
        double ratioMin = (Reference.UNITS_IMPOSSIBLE / (double)(a * Reference.UNITS_INGOT));
        for (int i = 0; i <= (int)(100 / Reference.UNITS_IMPOSSIBLE); i++){//for every ratio possible
            double currentRatio = round(i * ratioMin, 6);
            System.out.println("Testing for ratio: " + currentRatio);
            for (int b = 0; b <= ingotMaterialMaximum; b++){//with every amount of ingots
                for (int c = 0; c <= oreMaterialsMaximum; c++){//with every amount of rich ore
                    for (int d = 0; d <= oreMaterialsMaximum; d++){//with every amount of normal ore
                        for (int e = 0; e <= oreMaterialsMaximum; e++){//with every amount of poor ore
                            for (int f = 0; f <= oreMaterialsMaximum; f++){//with every amount of small ore
                                opt.set(null, null, null, a); //only the ingots are passed in this way
                                int[] res = opt.optimizeMaterial(new int[]{c, d, e, f, b}, currentRatio);
                                if (res != null){
                                    int units = 0;
                                    for (int j = 0; j < res.length; j++)
                                        units += res[j] * Reference.MATERIAL_UNITS[j];
                                    double unitsRight = Math.round(a * Reference.UNITS_INGOT * currentRatio);
                                    if (units != (int)unitsRight){ //if the units are not correct, log
                                        writer.println("I: " + a + " Rat: " + currentRatio + " I_av: " + b + " O_Ri: " + c + " O_No: " + d +
                                                " O_Po: " + e + " O_Sm: " + f + " units_wrong: " + units + " units_right: " + (int)unitsRight);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Testing done");
    writer.close();
}
```

Comment: What makes something *not* thread-safe? (Hint: loops are irrelevant, as is all the code posted, excluding where the answer to previous question is violated.)

Comment: Dude.. You've gotto check your design again.. So many loops?

Comment: You can tell just by looking this code needs to be cleaned. There is a lot of code duplication, which is what a programmer tries to avoid the most, and you have 8 loops imbricated... Even if your algorithm required it, it would not be a reason to not create some intermediate methods to make the code readable. Finally, when you say "I've been reading around and google says that as far as I don't have any local variables, I'm fine", in fact it is the exact opposite. Local variables are not shared so they don't present any risk.

Comment: @TheLostMind Yeah I know but my algorithm actually requires this many arguments. There is a loop for each one of them. I didn't really want to spend much time on writing this program, because its designed to test if the algorithm doesn't give any false positives. I could make it skip a few iterations but I didn't know which ones, its really complex.

Comment: @jammaster - Are you sure you can't use *recursion* ?

Comment: That would for sure make me run out of memory. I had it running for 8 hours now and it has only tested about 7 out of 30 possibilities. I interrupted it because I wanted my computer back :D. But there were no errors so far, so I'm just going to leave it as it is, the algorithm should work for all the cases if it worked for 7 now when I think of it. I thought it would run a little bit faster. And seriously, trying to optimize this program will take as much time as it would take me to finish the application itself, so I'm not going to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "do not use static variables" advise is indeed too simplistic: the other requirement is to not pass shared objects to `static` methods running in different threads.

Loop counters and other primitive local variables are thread-safe. The only thing that could make a method non-thread safe is shared state. It appears that you have successfully avoided that by creating separate `CrucibleOptimizer` and `PrintWriter` objects.

One refactoring that I would attempt is combining your `Runnable`s. Make a named class that takes loop boundaries, and make four instances of that class in your `main`. This would work better than four separate anonymous classes that have very few differences:

```
private static class ThreadRunnable implements Runnable {
    final String fileName;
    final int[] loopBoundaries;
    public ThreadRunnable(String fn, int[] lb) {
        fileName = fn;
        loopBoundaries = lb;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        PrintWriter pw;
        try {
            pw = new PrintWriter(fileName);
            CrucibleOptimizer co = new CrucibleOptimizer();
            opt(co, pw, loop4boundries[0], loop4boundries[1]);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can make four `ThreadRunnable` instances which share identical code.

Comment: I know that it looks bad, but this is only a one-time-use program, so i don't mind it looking like this. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Loops in of themselves are thread safe, so no you don't need to worry about that.

The only thing you need to worry about is anything that might be accessed by multiple threads at once.

However your entire architecture really needs some work.

For example why have 4 separate implementations for the runables rather than having one implementation and passing parameters into it to say which chunk to work on.

I also don't know what you are trying to do with all the loops but it's highly unlikely you really need any structure like that.

Comment: Yeah i know that it looks bad, but this is only one-time-use program. All the loops are to test every possible combination of parameters that can be passed to CrucibleOptimizer. I could have made it skip some useless iterations, but this works fine, especially since I don't mind this program running for a few hours.